# setOnItemSelectedListener on spinner is called when activity is show

Tags: android, spinner, tabactivity

I need to change the language of my application. For this I have a spinner that contains all the languages necessary for my application. Here is how I use it :

```
private Spinner language;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner_textview, languages);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item);
language.setAdapter(adapter);
language.setSelection(Integer.valueOf(languageId) - 1);
language.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
```

where CustomOnItemSelectedListener() :

```
private class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(language.getSelectedItemId() + 1));

             fsmApplication.setPreferredLanguageShortName(language.getSelectedItem());
             finish();
             Intent i4 = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,
             AccountActivity.class);
             startActivity(i4);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }

    }
```

The problem is very strange. This code is in SettingsActivity.class and it is inside on a Tab (it represents the second tab). When I click this tab (the second one), the application goes immediately in first tab (which contains the class AccountActivity). This means that setOnItemSelectedListener is called when I click the tab. Why is happening this ?
Here is my SettingActivity.class : http://pastebin.com/vLfZe61b

Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess it is because you call `language.setSelection(Integer.valueOf(languageId) - 1);`

Comment: I need to call this for being displayed the current language of the application. I can make this in a different way ?

Comment: This is probably not the best way, but you could introduce a _boolean_ value. And then you always set this _boolean_ to `true` before you call the `setSelection(..)`-method and then check for this _boolean_ in the listener.